# How do I read in multiple data sets?

Tags: r, dataset

What code do I need to read multiple data sets into R ?

For a single dataset I use:

```
File <- read.csv("C:\MyFile.CSV", header=T)
```

But I need to compare up to 20 different datasets.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: For the code dataFiles <- lapply(Sys.glob("data*.csv"), read.csv) do I need to have data in front of the names of my .csv files? Thanks?

Comment: Yes indeed, or you can of course adapt the code based on how your files are named.

Answer (score 1):

I would put all the CSV files in a directory, create a list and do a loop to read all the csv files from the directory in the list.

```
setwd("~/Documents/")
ldf <- list() # creates a list
listcsv <- dir(pattern = "*.csv") # creates the list of all the csv files in the directory
for (k in 1:length(listcsv)){
 ldf[[k]] <- read.csv(listcsv[k])
}
str(ldf[[1]])
```